# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
income=float(input("enter the annual income: ")

if income<85528:
  tax=(income-556.02)*0.18
else:
  tax=(income-85528)*0.32+14839.02

tax=round(tax,0)
print("the tax is: ", tax, "thalers")
```

Why does it keep giving an error on line 2?

Answer (score 3):

You have a lacking parenthesis in the 1st line: ")". It can be fixed by:

```
income = float(input("enter the annual income: "))
```

Complete program:

```
income = float(input("enter the annual income: "))

if income < 85528:
    tax = (income - 556.02) * 0.18
else:
    tax = (income - 85528) * 0.32 + 14839.02

tax = round(tax, 0)
print("the tax is: ", tax, "thalers")
```

Returns:

```
enter the annual income: 435
the tax is:  -22.0 thalers
```